# How to install gems with system wide rbenv by using chef

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, rbenv

I installed `rbenv` system wide (in `/usr/local/rbenv`) in my VPS.
And I want to install gems by using `chef`.

I tried like this, but the gem is installed in system default ruby.

```
gem_package "daemons" do
    action :install
end
```

How can I install gems in system wide rbenv?

By following coderanger's advice, I installed rbenv cookbook by Berkshelf.
After that I edited recipe file like this:

```
include_recipe "rbenv::default"
include_recipe "rbenv::ruby_build"

rbenv_ruby "2.0.0-p451"

rbenv_gem "daemons" do
    ruby_version "2.0.0-p451"
end
```

Then I got a error `` ERROR: No resource, method, or local variable named `rbenv_root_path' for `Chef::Recipe "default"' ``. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`rbenv_gem`](https://github.com/RiotGames/rbenv-cookbook#rbenv_gem) resource.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I couldn't install the gem yet. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I forgot to add `depends 'rbenv'` in `metadata.rb`. That was the reason I failed.